# How to get ip address using Port number in UDP networking?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp

It's a basic question and i'm learning basic networking, so sorry if i'm wrong.Can we convert a port number into an ip address in UDP networking?

Comment: In short, NO. I suggest you read networking fundamentals for that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `IP address` is the address used at the *Network layer* (Layer 3 in the *OSI Refference model*) while `UDP` works on the *Transport layer* (Layer 4), and a `port number` is here ***added*** to the `IP address`. So the *full* Layer 4's address is something as `IP address:port number`.

Think about postal addresses, something as *"Walnut Street 12"*. Let `IP address` is the name of the street (in this case *Walnut Street*) and the `port number` is the number of house in this street (*12*). How to obtain the street name from a number *12* only?